# Moov atom not found on Raspberry Pi platform (Linux)

Tags: codec, mp4

I have asked this question on innumerable sites but I haven’t been able to get an answer to solve my problem.  The question

[Need help to fix a broken MP4 which lacks a MOOV atom](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29073/need-help-to-fix-a-broken-mp4-which-lacks-a-moov-atom)

Seems to be on point since I am having a very similar problem.  But mine should be much, much simple.

I am ripping DVDs for personal use to stream on Plex.  The tool I am using is MacX DVDRipper Pro and also MakeMKV.  Both work just fine on my Mac as does HandBrake.  The videos play as expected on the Mac whether the container is mkv or mp4 or run through HandBrake with Web Optimized (moov atom in front of file) or not.  Everything seemed good at this point.

When I move to my RPi4 some work and some don’t.  At first I figured it was an issue with Plex but as I found by running mediainfo, ffmpeg, and AtomicParsley the ones that don’t play on that platform have limited XML information or errors.  Below are links to screen shots.  I can also provide hex pictures if desired.

The following examples are for an episode that works on RPi (moov atom at bottom of file)

https://share.getcloudapp.com/E0u9br9G

https://share.getcloudapp.com/BluYZ1KB

https://share.getcloudapp.com/8Lukjr5Z

The following are the same utilities as above but with an episode that fails on RPi (moov atom at the bottom of the file)

https://share.getcloudapp.com/X6u9Odb2

https://share.getcloudapp.com/BluYZ1DG

https://share.getcloudapp.com/jkuelDEG

Comment: Questions about DVD ripping and personal movie/series collections are not production related and therefore off-topic.

Comment: I understand but I noticed solutions that may be related in this group.  Is there anywhere other than stackexchange where I can put this since it is specific to video?

Comment: Does the latter file run fine on the Mac? If yes, then it looks to be an issue with copying the file onto RPi

Comment: There is the Raspberry Pi SE https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ which is relevant if there the issue is related to the Raspberry and for questions on Raspberry specific software. There is also an SE for software recommendations if you want to look for another tool https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ In either case read the help pages to find out what exactly is on topic.